# Backbone/Laravel: How to post to a different table

Tags: backbone.js, laravel

Here's my dilemma.  I have a series of tables with leads from our various contact forms.  We also have tables for spam that comes in on our forms.  But occasionally, a lead may get routed incorrectly to a spam table.  So I need to move that lead from one table to the other, which means inserting it one and deleting it from the other.

As I understand it, when Backbone calls the `save` method, it checks to see if that id exists in the table.  If it doesn't, it makes a POST request.  If it does, it makes a PUT request.  I need to be able to force Backbone to make a POST request, so that Laravel can call the right RESTful action.

See the problem is that if Backbone makes a PUT request to say, `/send-message/52` (the 52 being the ID of the lead in the send-message-spam table), it will update/overwrite the existing lead with the ID of 52.  I want to make a POST request to `/send-message` (obviously without an ID).

I can force Backbone to use a different `urlRoot`, but how do I force it to make a POST when I call `save()`?

Comment: I was reading up on `emulateHTTP` and that won't do what I want since it is just faking a PUT request.  It still calls the `update` method in Laravel, which is what receives a PUT request.

Comment: Part of the problem is that I have some code in my `update` method already that I don't want called.  I want to call a completely different set of code.

Comment: I tried saving to a different route, and it made a PUT request instead.  How do I get it to make a POST request?

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure if there is a configuration option to do this, but you could always override the save method in your Backbone model to have it perform the action you desire.

Comment: I hadn't considered that.  Hmm.